# Custom domain feature for saas product customers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I have build a saas product with angular 4 integrated with golang rest api and uploaded the build on aws ec2 instance. My project is a multi-tenant based app which loads customers dashboard on merchant-name.mystore.com subdomain but some of the customers asking for custom domain feature like they should be able to load the app on mydomain.com .

I have done the the subdomain part with following code in apache2.conf file so all subdomain loads from apps folder where the angular app files located

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.mystore.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    <Directory "/var/www/html/apps">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For custom domain feature I have a section in admin to save custom domain but not sure how should I implement it.

possible method I thought about are

1. Create virtual host file and update it on each merchant signup with his custom domain
2. Do it somehow with htaccess file and mod_rewrite

Shopify do it but not sure how they load merchant specific store. Another point kept me busy thinking about is what values should I ask to update

1. IP address on domain registrar
2. Name servers ( not sure what it will be for my on aws )
3. Ask to create CNAME or A record as some of the article suggest

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have a similar setup on a number of SaaS platforms I develop and manage. This type of setup is certainly desirable, as your clients suggest. You should plan to serve each customer site on its own domain, probably also with *SSL, from the begining. In my opinion, this is best practice for a well architected Saas service today.

In reading your question, I think you are over engineering it a little.

For a custom domain Saas app on the same server, you simply open port 80 to **all traffic**, *regardless of domain name*. Point all customer domains to `app.mystore.com`, which is a CNAME to your app endpoint.

The app then reads the HTTP request header, and in that way determines the host name that was requested.

Finally the app looks up the host name in its client database, and locates the client record for the give customer domain.

For example, in Nginx all you need is:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/myservice/htdocs;
}
```

This server configuration provides a catch all for any domain that points to this endpoint.

That is all the web server should need to allow it to answer to any customer domain.  The app must do the rest.

***** When you serve a custom domain on an app on this domain, you should plan to serve the SSL endpoint for the domain, eg https://www.mycustomdomain.com. Consider this in your architecture design. Consider also the DNS issues also if your app fails over to a new IP.

Comment: How do you install a 3rd party SSL certificate for a domain you don't control on your server.  I have everything working with the CNAME i.e vanity.mycompany.com maps to app.mysaas.com . mysaas.com has a wildcard cert *.mysaas.com and vanity.mycompany.com has it's own cert, but I can't figure out how to stop the security warnings

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is satisfactory but it only skims over the most important part, and that is enabling HTTPS by issuing certificates for third-party domains.

If your customers just CNAME to your domain or create the A record to your IP and you don't handle TLS termination for these custom domains, your app will not support HTTPS, and without it, your app won't work in modern browsers on these custom domains.

You need to set up a TLS termination reverse proxy in front of your webserver. This proxy can be run on a separate machine but you can run it on the same machine as the webserver.

#### CNAME vs A record

If your customers want to have your app on their subdomain, e.g. `app.customer.com` they can create a CNAME `app.customer.com` pointing to your proxy.

If they want to have your app on their root domain, e.g. `customer.com` then they'll have to create an A record on `customer.com` pointing to your proxy's IP. Make sure this IP doesn't change, ever!

#### How to handle TLS termination?

To make TLS termination work, you'll have to issue TLS certificates for these custom domains. You can use Let's Encrypt for that. Your proxy will see the `Host` header of the incoming request, e.g. `app.customer1.com` or `customer2.com` etc., and then it will decide which TLS certificate to use by checking the SNI.

The proxy can be set up to automatically issue and renew certificates for these custom domains. On the first request from a new custom domain, the proxy will see it doesn't have the appropriate certificate. It will ask Let's Encrypt for a new certificate. Let's Encrypt will first issue a challenge to see if you manage the domain, and since the customer already created a CNAME or A record pointing to your proxy, that tells Let's Encrypt you indeed manage the domain, and it will let you issue a certificate for it.

To issue and renew certificates automatically, I'd recommend using Caddy, greenlock.js, OpenResty (Nginx).

tl;dr on what happens here;
Caddy server listens on 443 and 80, receives requests, issues, and renews certificates automatically, and proxies traffic to your backend.

#### How to handle it on the backend

Your proxy is terminating TLS and proxying requests to your backend. However, your backend doesn't know who is the original customer behind the request. This is why you need to tell your proxy to include additional headers in proxied requests to identify the customer. Just add `X-Serve-For: app.customer.com` or `X-Serve-For: customer2.com` or whatever the `Host` header is of the original request.

Now when you receive the proxied request on the backend, you can read this custom header and you know who is the customer behind the request. You can implement your logic based on that, show data belonging to this customer, etc.

#### More

Put a load balancer in front of your fleet of proxies for higher availability. You'll also have to use distributed storage for certificates and Let's Encrypt challenges. Use AWS ECS or EBS for automated recovery if something fails, otherwise, you may be waking up in the middle of the night restarting machines, or your proxy manually.

Alternatively, there have been a few services like [this](https://saascustomdomains.com) recently that allow you to add custom domains to your app without running the infrastructure yourself.

If you need more detail you can DM me on Twitter [@dragocrnjac](https://twitter.com/dragocrnjac)